# iterating dataframe columns after groupby

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to groupby a a csv data read to a dataframe using pandas. I am doing a groupby to user_id column and able to do so successfully. How can i retrieve the column data after the groupby result. my csv columns are line this:
, user_id, status

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("test1.csv"))
grouped=df.groupby('user_id')
#writer = csv.writer(open("rewww.csv", 'w'))
for user_id,status in grouped:
    print status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there

```
for ix, grouped_df in grouped:
    print grouped_df['status']
```